# Swift & Firebase - update database with dynamic key

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

Is there a way to update the database with a dynamic id as a key?

Let's say I want the database to look like this:

```
- Data
     - dynamic key
         - data 1
         - data 2
```

This key is supposed to grow every time `databaseRef.updateChildValues(addObject)` is being called.

Further more, is there a way to set a var as a key? I've tried this but it didn't work:

```
var addId: Int = 0

func updateData() {
        ...

        addId += 1

        let addObject = [
            addId: someData
            ] as [String: Any]

        databaseRef.updateChildValues(addObject)
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the push() key generated my Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547325/how-to-get-the-push-key-generated-my-firebase)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need `childByAutoId()`

```
let value:[String:Any] = ["key":"value"]
ref.child("Data").childByAutoId().setValue(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

The key doesn't grow. It's a key.

You can add additional child nodes *under* that key if that's what you mean but updateChild values will only add additional nodes if the node doesn't exist. Otherwise it will update that node.

Also, if you want to get a key to a new node you can do this

```
let childOfDataRef = your_fb.child("data").childByAutoId()
let key = childOfDataRef.key
```